# Bluetooth chat multithread is possible?

Tags: android, multithreading, bluetooth, chat

I'm trying to make a bluetooth chat where all people with bluetooth can send message to all device nerby. Is possibile for you, considering the bluetooth specific ? Because i find some problem. Many times the connection fail. Can you tell me if is possibile?

Comment: I don't believe you can multi-cast with a bluetooth connection if that is your intention.  There is only a network discovery protocol over multi-cast as I understand.

Comment: I don't want send a multicast packet. I do a connection in a separate trhead for all device found. With syncronized to manage the variable..